# Possibility to Add Markers on Google Map based only on Address at SQL Server 2008 with MVC 3

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I'm stuck in this situation that i need to Add a Google Map that will show His workers in SQL Server 2008 by their address and it seems that I'm having a hard time finding this solutions, is there anyone that can give me some insights and will guide me with this?

Comment: What do you EXACTLY want to do ? Add Markers on Google Maps via their adress (latitue longitude / human-readable format) stored in SQL Server ?

Comment: @AlexB is it possible on not using Longitude and latitude and use their address only that is stored in sql server?

Comment: No you can't. You have to use Geocoding API to change your adresses into latitude / longitude. Just take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding?hl=fr

Comment: @AlexB i just want to make this kind of google map like this and serve as my  reference : http://hotpads.com

Comment: This kind of Google map is a little bit more complicated that a "simple" google map. For your adresses, you have no choice : you have to use Geocoding as I linked it below.